# SQL developer, retriev one of the values last or first doesn't matter

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table called `generalledger_mgmt` that contains many columns. I wrote query to perform some operations and select some of them as below.

My problem is some of those rows comes duplicated (some times different signs, and some time the same sign but regardless, for my report I consider them duplicated) and I would like to retrieve only one of the rows (could be the last one or first one it doesn't really matter to me as long as I am getting one row per '`serial`') - how can I ajust my code to achieve that?

table:

| rowsortid | COMPANYID | serial | TRANSDATEID | AMOUNTLC | CURRENCYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20211109-ICJ-565 | SSE | 222 | 20211101 | 500 | SEK |
| 20211109-ICJ-564 | SSE | 222 | 20211105 | -500 | SEK |
| 20211109-ICT-562 | SSE | 202 | 20211001 | 600 | SEK |
| 20211109-ICK-568 | SSE | 210 | 20211201 | 200 | SEK |

in my code I am grouping by rowsortid cause it is the only one different from row till another. My main interest is to get one row per `serial`, so in this case the output should be:

| rowsortid | COMPANYID | serial | TRANSDATEID | AMOUNTLC | CURRENCYCODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20211109-ICJ-564 | SSE | 222 | 20211105 | -500 | SEK |
| 20211109-ICT-562 | SSE | 202 | 20211001 | 600 | SEK |
| 20211109-ICK-568 | SSE | 210 | 20211201 | 200 | SEK |

My code:

```
SELECT rowsortid
    ,COMPANYID 
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(INDIVIDUALCODE, '[^| ]+', 1, 1) as serial
    ,max(TRANSDATEID) 
    ,sum(AMOUNTLC) 
    ,max(CURRENCYCODE) 
FROM generalledger_mgmt
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND companyid = 'SSE'
    AND transdateid >= 20211101
    AND transdateid < 20220101
    AND accountno LIKE '3311%'
    AND HIERARCHYID LIKE '3311C%'
GROUP BY rowsortid
    ,COMPANYID
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(INDIVIDUALCODE, '[^| ]+', 1, 1)
ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(individualcode, '[^| ]+', 1, 1);
```

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:mysql] but also [tag:oracle-sqldeveloper]. I'm pretty sure Oracle SQL-Developer is for Oracle database only, not MySQL, right? So which brand of database are you really using? This might be important to get the best answers to your question.

Comment: individualcode ? I don't see that in your sample

Comment: @BillKarwin I meant as oracle sql not SSMS. The db I am working with is SQL Developer

Comment: @P.Salmon original tb has +200 col, I am using some regex on individualcode to extract serialNO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one row per id it must be the only column in the group by

> ```
> create table generalledger_mgmt (
> rowsortid varchar(25),
> COMPANYID varchar(5),
> serial int,
> TRANSDATEID varchar(25),
> AMOUNTLC int,
> CURRENCYCODE varchar(5)
> );
> insert into generalledger_mgmt values
> ('20211109-ICJ-565','SSE',222,'20211101', 500,'SEK'),
> ('20211109-ICJ-564','SSE',222,'20211105',-500,'SEK'),
> ('20211109-ICT-562','SSE',202,'20211001', 600,'SEK'),
> ('20211109-ICK-568','SSE',210,'20211201', 200,'SEK');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>      MAX(rowsortid)
>     ,COMPANYID 
>     ,MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR(serial, '[^| ]+', 1, 1)) as serial
>     ,max(TRANSDATEID) 
>     ,sum(AMOUNTLC) 
>     ,max(CURRENCYCODE) 
> FROM generalledger_mgmt
> WHERE 1 = 1
>     AND companyid = 'SSE'
>     AND transdateid >= 20211101
>     AND transdateid < 20220101
> GROUP BY 
>     COMPANYID
> ORDER BY MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR
> (serial, '[^| ]+', 1, 1));
> ```
>
> ```
> MAX(rowsortid)   | COMPANYID | serial | max(TRANSDATEID) | sum(AMOUNTLC) | max(CURRENCYCODE)
> :--------------- | :-------- | :----- | :--------------- | ------------: | :----------------
> 20211109-ICK-568 | SSE       | 222    | 20211201         |           200 | SEK
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a767a2c8a41923c2a68589232613b52f)*

Answer (score 0):

There are some columns in your query which are not in your table definition so I have removed them. The function `abs` should be quicker that a regex for saying that positive and negative serial numbers are the same.

> ```
> SELECT rowsortid
>     ,COMPANYID 
>     ,ABS(serial) as serial
>     ,max(TRANSDATEID) 
>     ,sum(AMOUNTLC) 
>     ,max(CURRENCYCODE) 
> FROM generalledger_mgmt
> WHERE 1 = 1
>     AND companyid = 'SSE'
>     AND transdateid >= 20211101
>     AND transdateid < 20220101
> GROUP BY rowsortid
>     ,COMPANYID
>     ,ABS(serial)
> ORDER BY ABS(serial);
> ```
>
> ```
> rowsortid        | COMPANYID | serial | max(TRANSDATEID) | sum(AMOUNTLC) | max(CURRENCYCODE)
> :--------------- | :-------- | -----: | :--------------- | ------------: | :----------------
> 20211109-ICK-568 | SSE       |    210 | 20211201         |           200 | SEK              
> 20211109-ICJ-565 | SSE       |    222 | 20211101         |           500 | SEK              
> 20211109-ICJ-564 | SSE       |    222 | 20211105         |          -500 | SEK
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fa4eb7ea7cdc06802cabcb93855a0c3)*

Comment: Thanks @Kendle, The tb has more than 200 cols & Serial is just regex to extract serialNo(doesnt have sign) the sign is only in amounts. the problem is still there becuz we have serial 222 double.The output needed is one row for serial 222, I appreciate the help